# Making a shortcut for console object

Tags: javascript

For the sake of typing I'd like to have a variable `c` as the shortcut for `console`, so to be able to type `c.log('blabla')`. I tried

```
var c = console; // no avail
var c = new console; // nada
```

Is this feasible in JS?
Thanks

Comment: `var c = console` will work fine.

Comment: @SLaks LOL I was gonna comment it, but decided I want more rep. Anyway, you are 100% correct. `var` and `const`'s only difference is that `const` cannot be later changed, `var` can.

Comment: "no avail" isn't a problem description.

Comment: @TyQ. Not true about `var` vs `const`. Yes, `const` can't be changed but also `const` are block-scoped, while `var` may pollute global scope. `var` has execution context scope, if it's inside function it will not leak. To "fix" `var` issues we have `let`, which i recommend to use instead of `var`. It's same as `var` just also has block-scope.

Answer (score 3):

`console` is an object. Such as `var e = {}; e.test = function(){console.log('test')};` so, you can't use it as `var e = console()` because console is an object, not a function. However, you can store functions in an object.

```js
const c = console;
c.log('test');
```

**EDIT**: the reason it may not be working, if it's in an external script, is because you're not defining it using the `window` object. You can also do it like this:

```js
const c = window.console;
c.log('test');
```

Comment: The OP isn't doing `var e = console()`, but `var c = new console`, however the OP also claims `var c = console;` isn't working, is there any reason it would work with `const` instead ?

Comment: @adeneo You are completely right. I went ahead and edited the code. The first portion of my answer really isn't that relevant, it's just a *little* explanation as to why `c = new console` or `c = console()` will not work.

Comment: Yes it works, can't say what I was referencing. Thanks for the additional info!